# 'call' was called on null for parent callback function from stateful widget

Tags: flutter, widget

I want to have a multi-section form which has several subforms which when completed and validated will callback to the parent widget in order to go to the next subform.

my issue is I keep getting an error saying the function is null and I'm not sure why.

iv tried having a function within the StatefulWidget of the child but I always get an error saying the function is null when calling the parents passed through 'complete' function.

```
I/flutter (23821): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (23821): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter (23821): The method 'call' was called on null.
I/flutter (23821): Receiver: null
I/flutter (23821): Tried calling: call()
```

I thought I was doing it correctly but am a bit lost on what to try next, here is my code :

parent widget

```
class CreateForm extends StatefulWidget {

  CreateForm({
    Key key
  }): super(key: key);

  CreateFormState createState() => CreateFormState();
}

class CreateFormState extends State < CreateForm > {

  bool userDetailsCompleted = false;

  final formKey = GlobalKey < FormState > ();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return !userDetailsCompleted ? UserDetailsForm(
      completed: () {
        print("testing");
        // setState(() {
        //   userDetailsCompleted = true;
        // });
      },

    ) : nextSection(

    );
  }
}
```

child widget

```
class UserDetailsForm extends StatefulWidget {

  final Function completed;

  UserDetailsForm({
    @required this.completed,
    Key key
  }): super(key: key);

  UserDetailsFormState createState() => UserDetailsFormState();

}

class UserDetailsFormState extends State < UserDetailsForm > {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
        child: CustomButton(
              size: 15,
              text: 'Submit',
              onPressed: () {
                print('UserDetails account form submit');
                widget.completed();
              },
            )
          );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code locally, and it works. I think you just need to restart the Flutter, as maybe you just replaced Stateles to Stateful widget a moment before

### Fully-working repo

You can build it locally also in this [Github repo](https://github.com/ejabu/flutter_tricky_layout/blob/master/lib/j_screen/simple_callback.dart)

#### demo

[image: Code]